# Install Firefox Developer Edition, but keep / sync all my old settings / extensions / bookmarks / history, everything?

Tags: firefox

I installed the PPA and it got rid of my old FF, as intended, but didn't seem to have any of my old settings, extensions, or anything... removing it reverts to my old FF and old profile.

Is there an easy way to keep my current profile / everything, but upgrade to FF developer?

Comment: create file **ignore-dev-edition-profile** in **~/.mozila/firefox** Exp.  `touch ~/.mozilla/firefox/ignore-dev-edition-profile`

Comment: Hey, sorry to get back to you so late, I'll give it a try today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`touch ~/.mozilla/firefox/ignore-dev-edition-profile`

Creating this file and following the steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-daily/firefox-aurora
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Did the trick.